# How to disable background when modal window pops up

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I am building on a webpage template and made some modifications for modal pop up as given below:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="background-color:#FECE1A;display:none;width:750px;left:46%" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <script>
    $("#myModal4").on("show", function () {
      $("body").addClass("modal-open");
    }).on("hidden", function () {
      $("body").removeClass("modal-open")
    });
  </script>
  <!--Modal Content-->
  </div>
</div>
```

and the body.modal-open css function goes like this

```
body.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

the popup works fine. The problem is that whenever the pop up appears I can still click the header menu of the template and some links in the background. How do I disable everything in the background such that I can click only what is available at the popup.

Comment: How about using overlay?

Comment: you need to add an overlay with opacity less than 0.5

Comment: @SagarV Why does the opacity have to be less that `0.5`? Any value for this property should work for OPs purpose.

Comment: Yes but an overlay should contain a solid color (won't make a good design). It should be transparent @Toastrackenigma

Comment: What modal script are you using?

Comment: @SagarV that is very subjective.

Comment: @SagarV From a design perspective I agree that modals should have a transparent overlay behind them to visually confirm to users that other elements are not clickable - this is good UX. However your comment made it sound as if this was a technical requirement, which of course it is not.

Comment: then I didn't understood why you did so in the answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use an overlay - another div the full size of the screen that covers the html, with the bonus of giving a translucent grey shadow over the body.

In this example, use two divs.

One is the overlay, and the other (inside the overlay for convenience) is the modal.

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="modal">
    This is the modal. You can put whatever you like in here.
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the overlay needs styles:

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed; /* Positioning and size */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(128,128,128,0.5); /* color */
  display: none; /* making it hidden by default */
}
```

and the modal needs some too:

```
.modal {
  position: fixed; /* positioning in center of page */
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  height: 400px; /* size */
  width: 600px;
  background-color: white; /* background color */
}
```

Include jQuery by putting this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In the head tag at the top of your code.

Then, use this button to open the modal:

```
<button onclick="$('.overlay').show();">Open modal</button>
```

and this jQuery code to catch click on the overlay but not its child.

```
$('.overlay').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this) {
    return;
  }
  $('.overlay').hide();
});
```

```js
$('.overlay').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this) {
    return;
  }
  $('.overlay').hide();
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(128,128,128,0.5);
  display: none;
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk">This is a link, but with the modal open you can't click it!</a>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="$('.overlay').show();">Open modal</button>

<div class="overlay">
  <div class="modal">
    This is the modal. You can put whatever you like in here.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the code is working but i could not use it on my project, but it helped me a lot to solve the problem... thank you very much.

Comment: This way is good, but still can focus elements using Tab.

Answer (score 6):

### Introduction

A simple solution would be to add a `<div>` that covers the background, and is positioned below the popup but above all other content.

Below is a very simple example of what I would imagine you are trying to do. Hopefully you can adapt it to suit your scenario.

### Example

```js
function openModal() {
  $("#overlay").css({"display":"block"});
  $("#modal").css({"display":"block"});
}
```

```css
#modal {
  position:fixed;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  border:solid 1px #000;
  display:none;
  background-color:#fff;
}

#overlay {
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  display:none;
  background-color:#000;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Awesome Content!

<button onclick="openModal()">Open Modal!</button>

<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="modal"><h1>Modal Content!</h1></div>
```

### Key Points

- The `#overlay` div came before the `#modal` div - this is how I set the modal to be on top. Alternatively you could use `z-index` in CSS;
- The `opacity` value is not required here, it is simply used as a demonstration of where the overlay is in relation to the page / modal;
- None of the implementation details here matter. The JavaScript should not be important, neither should most of my CSS. The example simply exists to point you in the right direction.

Comment: 1) your modal doesn't close 2) you don't need to set the height of body and html because you can use `width: 100vw;` (vw is viewport width. 100vw is 100% of the viewport width) and `height: 100vh;` (vh is viewport height)

Comment: @JamesDouglas My modal does not need to close - I am simply demonstrating how a background overlay would work, not how the Javascript would work (it is fairly simple). Thanks for reminding me about `vh` and `vw` though - I will edit my post to use these units instead.

Comment: though it was not the solution, it helped to get an insight on the matter... thank you very much :) (y)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of using CSS property `pointer-events` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

Example: https://codepen.io/zvona/pen/YxQzEO

The key idea is to have `pointer-events: none;` for the body when modal is open. But the specific elements you want to be interacted with should have e.g. `pointer-events: auto;`.

In the example you can click both buttons when dialog is hidden, but only *Toggle Dialog* button when dialog is shown.

Comment: This answer is cleaner than any others and should become the accepted answer.

Comment: Agreed that this answer appears cleaner, and easier, than the others.  The others seem like more of a hack compared to this answer.